# Select query with comma and join

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join, find-in-set

I have tbl A and tbl B as below and I would like to get their names which is seperated by comma but I am not getting in the format I am looking for.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/149093/10

User: 1,2,3 ;2 - I should also get names A,B,C and then B But I am getting only A and B.
How should I get their individual names who are in the column user and also satisfy the condition  that 2 at least exists.Thanks in Advance.

Expected output is :

entire row with A
 entire row with B
 entire row with C
 entire row with A

Basically 4 rows as there are 4 users in total with their name .

```
|  USER | CATEGORY | USERNAME |
|-------|----------|----------|
| 1,2,3 |        1 |       A  |
| 1,2,3 |        1 |       B  |
| 1,2,3 |        1 |        C |
|     2 |        1 |        B |
```

Comment: whats is xpected output ? its not clear in question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT a.user, a.category, b.username 
FROM tblA a 
JOIN tblB b ON find_in_set(b.userid,a.user) 
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(2,a.user)
ORDER BY a.user;
```

Check the [**SQL FIDDLE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/149093/35)

**OUTPUT**

```
|  USER | CATEGORY | USERNAME |
|-------|----------|----------|
| 1,2,3 |        1 |        A |
| 1,2,3 |        1 |        B |
| 1,2,3 |        1 |        C |
|     2 |        1 |        B |
```

Comment: This is really close how can I get 4 rows instead of 2 and also can you please explain the query .It would help me a ton.Thanks

Comment: added expexted result.But can you explain the query above I tried a lot for the result you gave but I couldn't arrive at the result.Thanks

Comment: Super +1.I have forgotten to join another table which is on created_by_sno I will update it in another question and tag you .Please look into it.Thanks again .Have a great day.

Comment: by the way it should be A B C B .But it is ABBC .How should I get the former order?

Comment: Awesome .I will keep you posted with updated Q .Thanks .

Answer (score 0):

You should not use

```
('1,2,3', '1'),
('1,4,5', '2'),
('1,3,5', '3'),
```

to add multiple users to the same category. Instead, use the format you've used below that already to add users to categories:

```
('1', '1'),
('2', '1');
```

So, instead of: `('1,4,5', '2'),`

Use: `('1', '2'), ('4', '5'), ('1', '2'),`